# plane bombing problems- help

Tags: algorithm

I'm training code problems, and on this one I am having problems to solve it, can you give me some tips how to solve it please.

The problem is taken from here:

https://www.ieee.org/documents/IEEEXtreme2008_Competitition_book_2.pdf

Problem 12: Cynical Times.

The problem is something like this (but do refer to above link of the source problem, it has a diagram!):

Your task is to find the sequence of points on the map that the bomber is expected to travel such that it hits all vital links. A link from A to B is vital when its absence isolates completely A from B. In other words, the only way to go from A to B (or vice versa) is via that link.

Due to enemy counter-attack, the plane may have to retreat at any moment, so the plane should follow, at each moment, to the closest vital link possible, even if in the end the total distance grows larger.

Given all coordinates (the initial position of the plane and the nodes in the map) and the range R, you have to determine the sequence of positions in which the plane has to drop bombs.

This sequence should start (takeoff) and finish (landing) at the initial position. Except for the start and finish, all the other positions have to fall exactly in a segment of the map (i.e. it should correspond to a point in a non-hit vital link segment).

The coordinate system used will be UTM (Universal Transverse Mercator) northing and easting, which basically corresponds to a Euclidian perspective of the world (X=Easting; Y=Northing).

Input
Each input file will start with three floating point numbers indicating the X0 and Y0 coordinates of the airport and the range R. The second line contains an integer, N, indicating the number of nodes in the road network graph. Then, the next N (<10000) lines will each contain a pair of floating point numbers indicating the Xi and Yi coordinates (1 < i<=N). Notice that the index i becomes the identifier of each node. Finally, the last block starts with an integer M, indicating the number of links. Then the next M (<10000) lines will each have two integers, Ak and Bk (1 < Ak,Bk <=N; 0 < k < M) that correspond to the identifiers of the points that are linked together.

No two links will ever cross with each other.

Output
The program will print the sequence of coordinates (pairs of floating point numbers with exactly one decimal place), each one at a line, in the order that the plane should visit (starting and ending in the airport).

```
Sample input 1

102.3 553.9 0.2 
14 
342.2 832.5 
596.2 638.5 
479.7 991.3 
720.4 874.8 
744.3 1284.1 
1294.6 924.2 
1467.5 659.6 
1802.6 659.6 
1686.2 860.7 
1548.6 1111.2 
1834.4 1054.8 
564.4 1442.8 
850.1 1460.5 
1294.6 1485.1 
17 
1 2 
1 3 
2 4 
3 4 
4 5 
4 6 
6 7 
7 8 
8 9 
8 10 
9 10 
10 11 
6 11 
5 12 
5 13 
12 13 
13 14 

Sample output 1
102.3 553.9 
720.4 874.8 
850.1 1460.5 
102.3 553.9
```

Comment: What language should you use? Also, don't expect anyone to do it for you. People can give you hints, but that's it.

Comment: Hmmm. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: Best tip I can give is that you should make a start on your homework yourself and ask for specific help with specific problems.  As posted, your question is too long and too dense for me to try to start helping.  I'd only tackle it if I was getting some of the credit.

Comment: This does not look like homework to me. Besides, the first line is: "I'm training code problems", which I presume is programming contest type problems. Travelling Salesman is not right.

Comment: This is not homework, I am training to a programming contest that i will have next week.

Comment: @peiska: You problem description seems incomplete. Could you please re-check. Also, if possible, please link to the site where you got it from.

Comment: I've took it from herehttps://www.ieee.org/documents/IEEEXtreme2008_Competitition_book_2.pdf 
Problem 12 Cynical Times .

Comment: @peiska: I have added an answer, hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **Moron**' is right about the first part, but on the second part... 
The problem description does not tell anything about "smallest number of points". It tells that the plane flies to the closest vital link.
So, I think the part 2 will be much simpler:

- Find the closest non-hit segment to the current location.
- Travel to the closest point on the closest segment.
- Bomb the current location (remove all segments intersecting a circle)
- Repeat until there are no non-hit vital links left.

This straight-forward algorithm has a complexity of O(N*N), but this should be sufficient considering input constraints.

Comment: I believe the intent is to drop the least number of bombs, irrespective of the total distance travelled. The closest link is only to order the points based on distance to the airport to minimize risk of attack. (at least that is my interpretation)

Comment: @Moron: Dropping of the least number of bombs (which is not explicitly required by the problem statement) would require you to violate the "closest link" requirement (which **is** explicit). So, unless I am missing some parts of problem statement, the number of bombs dropped should not be minimal.

Comment: Well in that case, just select the closest link and be done with! I believe the closest link was only to determine the sequence of bomb droppings, and nothing else (_closest link possible_). The main goal is to get all the links (see first sentence of problem statement) which I believe translates to smallest number of bombs. Anyway...

Answer (score 1):

1. Pre-process the input first, so you identify the choke points. Algorithms like Floyd-Warshall would help you.
2. Model the problem as a Heuristic Search problem, you can compute a MST which covers all choke-points and take the sum of the costs of the edges as a heuristic.
3. As the commenters said, try to make concrete questions, either here or to the TA supervising your class.
4. Don't forget to mention where you got these hints.

Comment: Sorry, this does not seem obvious. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: From what I understood before the pointer to the problem statement was posted, it was all about finding a plan for the plane: i.e. fly from airport to location X, drop bomb at X, fly from location X to location Y, drop bomb at Y, etc. Your answer gives a very solid way of identifying such locations.

Comment: The search space would consist of what locations have been already bombed and the current plan location, actions that move from one state to the next (either fly-to or bomb), costs would be zero for bombing actions, flying action costs would be inv. proportional to dist between current plane location and target location.

Comment: Another possibility would be to - once your method to identify useful bombing regions is applied - model the whole thing as a STRIPS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STRIPS) Planning problem with costs, and use a good domain-independent planner to compute the plan, like the ones you can find here: http://ipc.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/HomePage

Comment: It all depends of the purpose of @peiska . I assumed he had the whole thing from scratch, if he can take off-the-shelf tools such as the planning algorithms I suggest, it all boils down to write a program which maps problems presented in the stated format into STRIPS problems, call a planner to solve the STRIPS problem and then map the solution given by the planner back to the representation required by the original problem stated.

Comment: And let me extend my excuses to @peiska - I wrongly assumed he was a somewhat cheeky undergrad looking for an easy way out of a hard programming assignment. Sorry @peiska :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be broken down into two parts.

1) Find the vital links.

These are nothing but the [Bridges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)) in the graph described. See the wiki page (linked to in the previous sentence), it mentions an algorithm by Tarjan to find the bridges.

2) Once you have the vital links, you need to find the smallest number of points which given the radius of the bomb, will cover the links. For this, for each link, you create a region around it, where dropping the bomb will destroy it. Now you form a graph of these regions (two regions are adjacent if they intersect). You probably need to find a minimum [clique partition](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ro/online/viggo_wwwcompendium/node25.html) in this graph.

Haven't thought it through (especially part 2), but hope it helps.

And good luck in the contest!